# @observable vs extendObservable usage

Tags: mobx

In [docs say](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observable-decorator.html) that

> @observable key = value; is sugar for extendObservable(this, { key: value })

And [works on Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ridermansb/x04g2o18/1/), so whats I'm doing wrong ?

Code..

```
class Data1 {
  @observable all = [];
}
```

should be the same as ..

```
class Data2 {
  constructor() {
    extendObservable(this, {
      all : [],
    })
  }
}
```

?

But..

### Tests ..

The test fail in Data1 ...

```
test('all should be defined', () => {
  const data1 = new Data1();
  expect(store.all).toBeDefined(); // FAIL, IS NOT EVEN DEFINED
});
```

But pass in Data2 ...

```
test('all should be an observable array', () => {
  const data2 = new Data2();
  const isObservable = isObservableArray(data1.all);
  expect(isObservable).toBeTruthy(); // PASS!!
});
```

### Babel

In my `.babelrc` I have ...

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [
            "last 2 versions", "ios_saf >= 8", "not IE <= 10",
            "chrome >= 51", "firefox >= 49", "> 1%"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-es2015-parameters",
    "es6-promise",
    "lodash"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transform-class-properties` must be **after** `transform-decorators-legacy`

I miss the documentation about [decorator usage](https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy#note-order-of-plugins-matters)..

> make sure that transform-decorators-legacy comes before transform-class-properties.